# Using Jython with Django?

Tags: python, jython

I am planning to use Jython with Django. I want to know how stable the Jython project is, how easy to use it is, and how large its developer community is.

Comment: This question is very broad and asks for subjective generalizations, it very hard to answer in a useful manner. 

In general see http://planet.jython.org/ and http://blog.leosoto.com/2010/01/django-jython-111-released.html for jython/django information.

Comment: Also see this link:

http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

to help you frame questions more effectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django is proven to work with Jython:

- Special focus in Jython 2.5 was to make it compatible with modern web frameworks like Django
- There is also a special project, [django-jython](http://code.google.com/p/django-jython/), that focuses on making database backends and extensions available for Jython development.
- There is explicit documentation on [how to run Django on Jython](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/)

In theory, Jython is 100% compatible with CPython. In practice, some extensions or libraries may have badly written code that make them dependent on a specific Python implementation such as CPython. The `django-jython` project explicitly provides a tested solution to overcome this problem. Of course you can still run across some libraries that explicitly require CPython (hence *mostly* safe).

Answer (score 3):

I have not used Django with Jython, so I can't speak to that specific issue, but I've used Jython for other things and I've found it quite stable of late, and just as easy as plain Python.  I believe the "core committers" in Jython are substantially fewer than in C-Python (maybe 1/3 the number or less), if that's what you mean by "developer community", but I'm not quite sure what's the point in asking about this -- are you considering joining either developer community (Jython or Core Python) and wondering where you could have the best impact?

If that's the case, I think the key issue isn't really how many others are already helping out, but, "what do you bring to the party" -- if you're a JVM wizard, or an expert at any important Java framework, you could be a real boon to the Jython community while that same skill would help much less in the C-Python community; vice versa, if you're a wizard, say, with autoconfigure and C-coded system calls, that would be precious for the C-Python community, but not as useful for the Jython community.

Answer (score 2):

I use Jython in testing and rapid-development. 
From my point of view it is stable.